# CSS Visiblity none vs collapse

Tags: html, css

What is difference between the below two?

1. `visibility:none;`
2. `visibility:collapse;`

`visibility: collapse` is only used in case of tables? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, `visibility: collapse` is only used in table elements.

> **hidden** The box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout.  Descendants of the element will be visible
>   if they have visibility:visible (this doesn't work in IE up to version
>   7).
>
> **collapse** For table rows, columns, column groups, and row groups the row(s) or column(s) are hidden and the space they would have
>   occupied is (as if display: none were applied to the column/row of the
>   table). However, the size of other rows and columns is still
>   calculated as though the cells in the collapsed row(s) or column(s)
>   are present. This was designed for fast removal of a row/column from a
>   table without having to recalculate widths and heights for every
>   portion of the table. For XUL elements, the computed size of the
>   element is always zero, regardless of other styles that would normally
>   affect the size, although margins still take effect. For other
>   elements, collapse is treated the same as hidden.

reference:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility